# How to correctly escape data

Tags: wordpress

I want to get recent posts and I use wp_get_recent_posts :

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => '3',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);?>
```

then I want to show posts info on page:

```
<?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){?>
    <li>
        <?php echo the_category('/','',$recent["ID"]); ?>
        <?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]) ?>
        <?php echo $recent["post_title"]?></h2>
        <?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y',$recent["ID"])?>
        <?php echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'bereza-carousel');?>
    </li>
    <?php
}?>
```

But all dynamic data must be correctly escaped. So how can I correctly escape data?